# Cannot build libboost_filesystem.a for boost_1.68.0 with qnx7.0based qcc

Tags: boost, qcc

Used the following options

1. ./bootstrap.sh--with-toolset=qcc
2. b2 toolset=qcc target-os=qnxnto threadapi=pthread link=static -l240 --layout=system --without-python cxxflags="-Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -Y_gpp -Wc,-std=gnu++0x -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN" linkflags="-Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -Y_gpp -lang-c++" -j7

seeing the following error

---

```
qcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\qcc\release\link-static\operations.o libs\filesystem\src\operations.cpp: In function 'void boost::filesystem::detail::permissions(const boost::filesystem::path&, boost::filesystem::perms, boost::system::error_code*)': libs\filesystem\src\operations.cpp:1486:11: error: '::fchmodat' has not been declared
       if (::fchmodat(AT_FDCWD, p.c_str(), mode_cast(prms),
           ^ cc: C:/Users/bilahari.akkiraju/qnx700/host/win64/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0eabi/5.4.0/cc1plus caught signal 1
    "QCC" -Wc,-ftemplate-depth-128 -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -Y_gpp -Wc,-std=gnu++0x -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -O3 -Wc,-finline-functions -Wc,-Wno-inline -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG -I"." -c -o "bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\qcc\release\link-static\operations.o" "libs\filesystem\src\operations.cpp"
...failed qcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\qcc\release\link-static\operations.o... ...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\qcc\release\link-static>libboost_filesystem.a for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\qcc\release\link-static>operations.o... ...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_filesystem.a for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\qcc\release\link-static>libboost_filesystem.a ...failed updating 1 target ...skipped 2 targets...
```

---

Building on my windows 10 machine , any idea on what can be done to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. This is caused by boost calling a function that does not exist in QNX 7 or older.

There is a bug entry for this issue with a possible solution:
https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/89

In short: add the following line to the function *"permissions"* in *"filesystem/src/operations.cpp"* for Boost 1.68.0 at line 1482:

`&& !(defined(__QNX__) && (_NTO_VERSION <= 700)) \`

Be aware that there is a version check for QNX 7 or older (_NTO_VERSION). Modify for future versions (see [_NTO_VERSION description](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/manifests.html)).

Best regards